# What does FPN in SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320 stand for?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, mobilenet

I was looking at the TensorFlow 2.0 Detection Zoo recently and found the `SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320` pre-trained model and was wondering what the FPN part in "FPNLite" means/stands for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for Feature Pyramid Network.
Its a subnetwork which outputs feature maps of different resolutions.
An explanation of FPN using detectron2 as an example is here: https://medium.com/@hirotoschwert/digging-into-detectron-2-part-2-dd6e8b0526e

Comment: Hello, could you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64621656/can-we-show-underfitting-with-mobilenet

Comment: What does 320 x 320 means ?

Comment: The resolution of the imput image

Answer (score 1):

A Feature Pyramid Network, or FPN, is a feature extractor that takes a single-scale image of an arbitrary size as input, and outputs proportionally sized feature maps at multiple levels, in a fully convolutional fashion. This process is independent of the backbone convolutional architectures.